# How to make an or condition with two constant color values?

Tags: pine-script

```
kcolor = iff( sqzval > 0,
     iff( sqzval > nz(sqzval[1]), color.lime, color.green),
     iff( sqzval < nz(sqzval[1]), color.red, color.maroon))
```

This is the relevant code. I have a variable with multiple conditions, so it will be `and (variable name)` something something. I want a condition that checks if `kcolor` is either `color.lime` or `color.maroon`, and likewise for `color.green` or `color.red`.

I've tried a couple ways but I haven't found anything that works. `kcolor = color.lime or color.maroon` doesn't work, it gives me a `syntax error at input 'kcolor'`. When I change the `=` to a `==`, it doesn't work because `Cannot call 'operator or' with arguments (series[bool], literal color)`.

I know that I most likely have to make a condition that outputs a boolean value, but I don't know exactly how to do that.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
limeOrMaroon = kcolor == color.lime or kcolor == color.maroon
greenOrRed = kcolor == color.green or kcolor == color.red
```

Comment: Thanks, although i figured it out a bit after, I used a different workaround (I posted it as an answer) but this one seems to be valid too.

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround I used. The above answer is valid too, this is what I came up with.

```
sqzmombull = iff( sqzval > 0,
     iff( sqzval > nz(sqzval[1]), true, na),
     iff( sqzval < nz(sqzval[1]), na, true))
     
sqzmombear = iff( sqzval > 0,
     iff( sqzval > nz(sqzval[1]), na, true),
     iff( sqzval < nz(sqzval[1]), true, na))
```